# TSQL and UNC Paths

Tags: file, t-sql, path, sql-server-2008-r2, unc

I'm not an expert with TSQL so have patience with me please.  So recently I was doing a project in TSQL on my local server using SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio. I was reading my files from a temp file on my `C:` drive and bulk inserting them into tables at the time.

Then I went and moved to a regular server instead of my local server on my machine.

It took me a bit to realize that I no longer had access to my local machine folders and files, and that is causing me issues.

I've read that one solution is to create a mapped drive on the server, but this is not an option for me.

So my question is what are other options for me? Could I use UNC paths to access my files or anything else?

The files I want to access are regular text files that are comma-delimited and newline terminated.

(I saw somewhat similar questions to mine, but there's seemed server specific or specific to their particular issues. Also none of their questions were answered.)

Comment: If you want to import those files into a remote SQL Server, that server machine must have access to the files. That's the case on the **local** drive(s) of that server machine - or on a **share** that is setup to be accessible by the server machine and user account running the SQL Server engine on that machine. One or the other - no "magic" trick for anything else, really.

Comment: @marc_s Not necessarily the server machine.  The account that the SQL Server instance is running as, or, if it's an SQL Agent task, the account that service is running as or impersonating.  That may be the SYSTEM account, or it may be one you've manually configured if you're following best practice with SQL Server editions released in the past 10 years.

Comment: @BaconBits: you're right - but there also needs to be a physical network connection from the server machine to the location where the network share is located - if that's not a given, then you won't get far ....

Answer (score 0):

Actually a mapped drive won't work either because the account SQL runs under by default (local system if I recall) will not have network access.

So, the more reliable way to do this is definitely with a UNC path BUT there is more! (I've done this several times when I've needed to move database backups and log backups across servers for mirroring).

How?

1. On the SQL server machine AND the other server that will host the share, create a new user (same username and password on both machines) - assuming your not using AD. The user needs not be in any groups at all other than the users group but it must be called the same in both servers and the password must match.
2. On the SQL server machine change the account that SQL SERVER is running under. This is done in the SQL server configuration tool. Do not try to do this yourself via windows services.  Choose the user that you created in no 1 above. Note you have to enter the pw. Restart SQL after you've changed it and verify SQL still runs fine. It should run just as before but now is running as a particular user with all the permissions of that user (which actually are very limited anyhow, but at least the user can access network resources).
3. On the remote server, make sure the new user has NTFS permissions on the folders that will host your share. Read/write perhaps or just read if SQL is only reading data.
4. On the remote server, create a share pointing to the appropriate folder that you set permissions for above. Make sure if you're using share permissions that the new user also has permissions on the share (not just on NTFS on the drive).

Once all of this is setup, your SQL scripts simply use the UNC path that points to the remote share and since SQL is running "as" a user with access to that share, SQL will see the files just fine!